# Joomla 2.5.14 mysql - memory issue

Tags: mysql, joomla

Can someone explain this Joomla error to me -- what to do to fix it.  It shows up with debug on. We seem to have a memory leak? Mysql runs slow than site crashes.

```
Function    Location
JSite->dispatch()   /home/greatfam/public_html/index.php:52
JComponentHelper::renderComponent() /home/greatfam/public_html/includes/application.php:197
JComponentHelper::executeComponent()    /home/greatfam/public_html/libraries/joomla/application/component/helper.php:351
require_once()  /home/greatfam/public_html/libraries/joomla/application/component/helper.php:383
JController->execute()  /home/greatfam/public_html/components/com_content/content.php:16
ContentController->display()    /home/greatfam/public_html/libraries/joomla/application/component/controller.php:761
JController->display()  /home/greatfam/public_html/components/com_content/controller.php:74
ContentViewArticle->display()   /home/greatfam/public_html/libraries/joomla/application/component/controller.php:722
JView->get()    /home/greatfam/public_html/components/com_content/views/article/view.html.php:32
ContentModelArticle->getItem()  /home/greatfam/public_html/plugins/system/jat3/jat3/core/joomla/view.php:348
JError::raiseError()    /home/greatfam/public_html/components/com_content/models/article.php:172
JError::raise() /home/greatfam/public_html/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:251
```

Comment: Not nearly enough information to evaluate this. Only clue is that it might be related to the T3 framework. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I updated the T3 framework and it didn't seem to make a difference. Is there some other information I can gather that would help?

Comment: Provide all of the relevant information, that you would like to see if you were in our place. What is your setup? What have you customized? How big is your data set? What have you tried so far? You will have to do most of the work here: find the relevant code section, log the SQL queries and try to see if they are to blame, show us the error messages themselves, use a debugger to step through code, etc. Getting a solution based on a stack trace only makes you a very lucky person.

Answer (score 2):

A nice and easy way to get started is: turn Joomla debug on in the Global configuration.

Then reload the frontpage, and examine closely the output at the bottom of the page.

There you will find the details of the memory used by each module, and the list of queries run.  This will give you a head start and limit the number of items you need to debug (there will be a single module eating up all your memory).

If "after dispatch" is taking too long, then it could be either a plugin or the component being shown on the page.

If nothing "notable" shows up here (a lot of queries, more than 50, or high memory consumption, or long time for a single item, you might want to look at the apache error_log and mysql log and verify system limits.